# Have two divs display on top of one another using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create what I thought would be fairly simple but I'm screwing it up bad.

I want to create two rows on top of each other. In each row, there will be five mini profiles side by side.

```
City 1


pic          pic       pic          pic      pic
name         name      name         name     name 
email        email     email        email    email 


City 2


pic         pic       pic            pic      pic
name        name      name           name     name
email       email     email          email    email
```

As you can see at this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/GRWZG/18/,  I'm totally screwing it up. I can't get the cities to stack on top of each other. And I can't put padding around each profile. In my fiddle, there are only supposed to be two profiles in each row.

Any suggestions for a newbie? thanks

Comment: Why do you include the term `JErk`? Do you have some subtle axe to grind?

Comment: ha, no, I was just trying to think up a name, and it's the first word that came to mind.

Comment: Even though it's vague, I have to admit I like the dramatic title to this question. We've all been there before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just needed to apply some similar selectors, i added some classes for you. pretty sure id="New York" is going to be invalid, but it doesn't affect styling: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/GRWZG/27/

Comment: thanks, this helps, but I still can't put space between each profile in each row.

Comment: like this? http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/GRWZG/51/  cityblock is the class that i made up, you could always just use .vancouver,.newyork,.genericcityname instead

Comment: yeah, that's better thanks, but when I tried to put margin between Vancouver and New York, it moved the profiles down, but the heading New York stayed as is, http://jsfiddle.net/GRWZG/60/  any ideas?

Comment: I think the markup is kinda wacky there (name, picture, etc as separate list items and as peers), let me offer this as a refinement http://jsfiddle.net/GRWZG/67/

Comment: @Michael since .city is clearing the floats, margin won't work so i added padding to it: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/GRWZG/71/

Comment: @steveax i agree, i just didn't want to chop up the markup without knowing what exactly was needed and wasn't

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your city divs, e.g. `div id="Vancouver"`. Style it to `float: left` and give it width 100%, e.g. `#Vancouver {float: left; width: 100%;}`.

http://jsfiddle.net/GRWZG/52/

Also I believe an id with two words like "New York" is not legal in HTML. Consider changing it to New-York.

Answer (score 1):

Delete all your css and replace it with `div {float: left; }`. That will get you started in the right direction. You are over thinking the problem and getting too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

style

```
#Vancouver {float:left; display:block; }
.vancouver {float: left;}
#New_York {clear:both; float:left; display:block;  margin-top:20px; }
.newyork {float: left; }
.vancouver a {padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;}
```

UPDATE:

```
#Vancouver {float:left; display:block; }
.vancouver {float: left; padding-right:20px;}
#New_York {clear:both; float:left; display:block;  margin-top:20px; }
.newyork {float: left; padding-right:20px; }
```

data

```
<div id="Vancouver">
 <div class="headVan">Vancouver</div>
 <div class="vancouver a">
  <ul>
   <li><img src="http://familylawact.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/1.png" alt ="test" /></li>
   <li>Tom JErk</li>
   <li>firm: </li>
   <li>tel: </li>
   <li>profile </li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="vancouver b">
  <ul>
   <li><img src="http://familylawact.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/2.png" alt ="test" /></li>
   <li>Sam JErk</li>
   <li>firm: </li>
   <li>tel: </li>
   <li>profile </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="New_York">
 <div class"headvic">New York</div>
 <div class="newyork a">
  <ul>
   <li><img src="http://familylawact.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/3.png" alt ="test" /></li>
   <li>Nat JErk</li>
   <li>firm: </li>
   <li>tel: </li>
   <li>profile </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="newyork b">
  <ul>
   <li><img src="http://familylawact.ca/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/4.png" alt ="test" /></li>
   <li>Jed JErk</li>
   <li>firm: </li>
   <li>tel: </li>
   <li>profile </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why float `#Vancouver` and `#New_York`? Just the clearing on `#New_York` should be enough (or add `overflow: hidden` to `#Vancouver` and `#New_York`).

Comment: thanks, but the padding between the profiles isn't working in yours. "vancouver a"

Comment: You have padding just for vancouver a. I would recomend, if I may, just use padding-right:10px for vancouver and for newyork. No need to code each a, b, c, d, e, .... (SEE UPDATED ANSWER [TOP])

Comment: o.k., thanks, got it. the other guy answered before you so I gave him accepted answer but I did vote you up. cheers

Comment: Appreciated! Not trying to robb anyone but the styling solution of mine is simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for your disaster is that there is `float` in the `child` `DIV's` but your are not `clear it's parent`. So, first `clear his parent` like this:

```
.city{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

check this exzmple http://jsfiddle.net/GRWZG/58/

Answer (score 0):

If the width of the DIV is set to 100% of the parent DIV the next DIV will automatically go under. if you do something like this

```
#A {
float: left; 
width: 20px;


}

#B {
float: left; 
width: 20px;


}

#C {
float: left; 
width: 20px;


}
```

And the width of the parent DIV 60, They'll all be in they'll be in the same row. If you create DIV's D, E, and F and their widths are 20px also, you'll have a second row of three DIV's. They follow each other in the other that you arrange but if the total width of the three exceeds 60px(parent DIV width), one of the DIV's will drop to the next row.